# NetworkOnMainThreadException questions?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a class/activity called EditTrip_Activity.java in my Android project and I keep getting this NetworkOnMainThreadException. I have gotten this before and fixed it by putting my code in the doInBackground() of an AsyncTask. I am doing a similar thing here, but it doesn't seem to work and I'm not sure why...

### EditTrip_Activity.java

```
public class EditTrip_Activity extends Activity {
EditText txtTripName;
EditText txtStartLoc;
EditText txtEndLoc;
EditText txtDistTravelled;
EditText txtCreatedAt;
Button btnSave;
Button btnDelete;

String tripid;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser_Helpers2 jsonParser = new JSONParser_Helpers2();

// single product url
private static final String url_product_details = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

// url to update product
private static final String url_update_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/update_product.php";

// url to delete product
private static final String url_delete_product = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/delete_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_TRIPS = "trips";
private static final String TAG_TRIPID = "tripid";
private static final String TAG_TRIPNAME = "tripName";
private static final String TAG_STARTINGLOCATION = "startingLoc";
private static final String TAG_ENDINGLOCATION = "endingLoc";
private static final String TAG_DISTANCETRAVELLED = "distanceTravelled";
private static final String TAG_CREATEDAT = "date";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_trip);

    // save button
    btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

    // getting product details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting product id (pid) from intent
    tripid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_TRIPID);

    // Getting complete product details in background thread
    new GetProductDetails().execute();

    // save button click event
    btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // starting background task to update product
            new SaveProductDetails().execute();
        }
    });

    // Delete button click event
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // deleting product in background thread
            new DeleteProduct().execute();
        }
    });

    //enable app icon as the up button to go back to previous screen as outlined in manifest xml
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
 * */
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditTrip_Activity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tripid", tripid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_trip_details, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Trip Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_TRIPS); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        // product with this pid found
                        // Edit Text                    
                        EditText txtTripName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                        EditText txtStartLoc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputStartLoc);
                        EditText txtEndLoc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEndLoc);
                        EditText txtDistTravelled = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDistTravelled);
                        EditText txtCreatedAt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCreatedAt);

                        // display product data in EditText
                        txtTripName.setText(product.getString(TAG_TRIPNAME));
                        txtStartLoc.setText(product.getString(TAG_STARTINGLOCATION));
                        txtEndLoc.setText(product.getString(TAG_ENDINGLOCATION));
                        txtDistTravelled.setText(product.getString(TAG_DISTANCETRAVELLED));
                        txtCreatedAt.setText(product.getString(TAG_CREATEDAT));
                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

There is more to this class in other Async Tasks but this is the one where the error is throw. Any idea what the problem is?

Here is the LogCat:

```
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at com.autotracker.activities.JSONParser_Helpers2.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser_Helpers2.java:71)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at com.autotracker.activities.EditTrip_Activity$GetProductDetails$1.run(EditTrip_Activity.java:148)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-23 21:20:41.024: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### Edit:

```
class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditTrip_Activity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

        // Edit Text                    
        txtTripName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputTrip);
        txtStartLoc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputStartLoc);
        txtEndLoc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputEndLoc);
        txtDistTravelled = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDistTravelled);
        txtCreatedAt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputCreatedAt);
    }

    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        JSONObject product = null;

        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tripid", tripid));

            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            // Note that product details url will use GET request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_trip_details, "GET", params1);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Single Trip Details", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully received product details
                JSONArray productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_TRIPS); // JSON Array

                // get first product object from JSON Array
                product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

            }else{
                // product with pid not found
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return product;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject product) {
        // dismiss the dialog once got all details
        pDialog.dismiss();

        try {
            // display product data in EditText
            txtTripName.setText(product.getString(TAG_TRIPNAME));
            txtStartLoc.setText(product.getString(TAG_STARTINGLOCATION));
            txtEndLoc.setText(product.getString(TAG_ENDINGLOCATION));
            txtDistTravelled.setText(product.getString(TAG_DISTANCETRAVELLED));
            txtCreatedAt.setText(product.getString(TAG_CREATEDAT));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### Fixed it!

Turns out the problem was with this line findViewById(R.id.inputName), it should have been inputTrip. Now its all fixed. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are contradicting almost all of your `AsyncTask` by runOnUiThread() within doInBackground() method. The point of the AsyncTask it to avoid blocking the UiThread by running in a seperate, background thread and also has the ability of updating the UI with preExecute() and postexecute().
 **EDIT** I would follow this general outline and create fields within you AsyncTask (sorry for lack of detail, typed from mobile) :

```
AsyncTask {

// Declare fields so you can access from all methods within class if needed
TextView tvProdDetail1, tvProdDetail2;
String prodDet1, prodDetail2;

    preExecute(){
    // Initialize field variables
    tvProdDetail1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_tv_1);
    tvProdDetail2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id. my_tv_2);
    } 

    doInBackground() {
    /Do network operations in background, set strings prodDetail1 and prodDetail2 to values retrieved from net
    } 

    post execute() {
    // set text() to TextViews
    tvProdDetail1.set text(prodDetail1);
    tvProdDetail2.set text(prodDetail2);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps clear things up for you, happy coding!

Comment: Thanks! I actually removed the runOnUiThread and now the background task seems to work fine, however, I'm not sure how to update the EditText text fields in onPostExecute. I am getting the values but I basically just moved my EditText lines from my previous code to onPostExecute() but no luck. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Updated answer, just follow that general outline and you should be good to go. If it works for you, don't forget to accept my answer ;)

Comment: Thanks! See my updated code in the original post, I am doing pretty much what you say, except that I have my EditText fields declared ourside the Async Task...now I am getting a NullPointerTask in onPostExecute() so I don't think I am returning properly from the doInBackground()

Comment: Found my problem, edited my original post with it. Thanks for the help Matt!

Answer (score 2):

by using `runOnUiThread()` inside your `doInBackground()` method, you are effectively removing any background threading you had, as everything is going to be run on the UI (main) thread, which will throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

To fix this, remove at least the line

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_trip_details, "GET", params);
```

from the `runOnUiThread()` call, preferably more if you can.

Comment: Thanks! I actually removed the runOnUiThread and now the background task seems to work fine, however, I'm not sure how to update the EditText text fields in onPostExecute. I am getting the values but I basically just moved my EditText lines from my previous code to onPostExecute() but no luck. I'll keep trying.

Comment: what do you mean by no luck? perhaps if you returned your product JSON object in doInBackground(), then you can use it in the onPostExecute() method

Comment: See updated code in my original post. I am returning the JSON object but am getting a NullPointerException in OnPostExecute(), working through that one now. Am I not returning correctly?

Comment: Found the problem, see solution in original post. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!